# After I register a copyright for my app, what do I get?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing

Lets say I took my app (source code) and registered it with the copyright office of my country.

After that what form of proof do I get?

Do I get papers that have my souce code printed on them and signed by the office?

Thanks.

Comment: Copyright law varies by jurisdiction. Right now, your question is effectively asking about every country in the world. Please include a tag or information indicating what country you are asking about.

Comment: My mind baffles at the thought of actually registering a specific set of source code files with a copyright authority, given how often source code changes...  What happens with the next update?  Have to reregister it?  New feature?  Bug fix?

Comment: @Moo shouldn't android developers register the code to prove authorship of the app?

Comment: As I say above, which version?  It’s going to change each time you make even the smallest modification, so.....  I wouldn’t bother tbh, you have copyright from the moment you save the first source code file, and having a decent history in git or other source control goes a long way toward proving provenance in any legal dispute.  I guarantee you that the vast majority of app devs never even consider registering, because it brings little benefit - they already have copyright protection under international law, registering just allows you to claim certain types of damage and a few other things.

Comment: @Moo what do you mean github?

Comment: @Moo what do you mean have history in git?

Comment: git has a cryptographic history of all commits, back to the first one (and yes, it can be faked, but its a lot of work to re-write all of gits history if you want to erase someone from it and still come out with a decent trail), so any git repo with a decent amount of commits should be able to go a long way to establishing provenance over the code.  Looking at one of my projects, I can see who did what and when on it, and see the code and product improve over the 3 years this repo has been in use, over thousands of commits.

Comment: @Moo so you mean a local repo or online one?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Moo I guess it does matter speaking about timestamps? Maybe locally one can manipulate time but online you cant manipulate timestamps?

Comment: Of course you can, I can still force push a changed repo to GitHub and change all of the commits, but the value of having this comes from the progression through the commits, the features they implement, the time they were done etc.  If someone wanted to fake an entire repo to the extent that they could claim ownership of it (ie rewrite the entire git history, removing you as committer and from comments etc) then they could do it, but they would have to be exceptional at doing it because its relatively easy to see when its been done.

Comment: @Moo I don't work with a team. And ofcourse you mean a private github, if I want to host my app progress?

Comment: You can use whatever you want (Github, Bamboo, Gitlab, host your own), Im talking about the value that git itself brings to this issue.

Comment: I've been writing code for 30 years now, worked on some humongous projects and earn a decent salary doing it - and not once did anyone involved in any of those projects during any of those 30 years even consider actually registering our source codes copyright.  And a quick straw poll of a few large dev communities show overwhelmingly that very few other devs consider it either (as in, out of a few active Slack channels with thousands of members in, not one has considered it in a poll running for about 5 hours now).

Comment: @Moo yes what shocks me is that no one ever talks about registering code with an office, alot told me to use git to make a time history of the progress to use it if someone else claims authorship of code. Its because I never used source control before, I am asking alot about same thing so sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

> Copyright James Daniel Marrs Ritchey. This material was created for
>   submission at
>   '[After I register a copyright for my app, what do I get?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48507/after-i-register-a-copyright-for-my-app-what-do-i-get)',
>   but can also be alternatively obtained from
>   'https://snippetly.blogspot.com/2020/01/what-you-recieve-when-registering.html'
>   under the terms of any of the following licenses: Ritchey Permissive
>   License v8
>   (https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2020/01/ritchey-permissive-license-v8.html),
>   The MIT License (https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), and the
>   WTFNMFPL-1.0
>   (https://tldrlegal.com/license/do-what-the-fuck-you-want-to-but-it's-not-my-fault-public-license-v1-(wtfnmfpl-1.0)#fulltext).

[In Canada](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/cipointernet-internetopic.nsf/eng/wr00039.html?Open&wt_src=cipo-cpyrght-main), you get a registration certificate. It doesn't state if the certificate is electronic, or paper. However, [you can request a copy](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/cipointernet-internetopic.nsf/eng/wr04196.html) in either form for an additional fee.